# How does firebase auth custom auth domain actually work?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase project set up where I am only using the firebase auth features. I have a react app that uses the firebase client-side javascript SDK for authentication and a custom backend + database that does **not** use any firebase features.

Currently when users are logging in with a popup flow, they see the auth domain "myappname.firebaseapp.com" as per the default firebase config. It all works great.

However, if I now want to set up a custom auth domain, what I've gathered from other answers is that I need to:

1. Add an authorized redirect URI in firebase console to point to my custom auth domain, say https://auth.myappname.com/__/auth/handler
2. Change authDomain in my client side code (firebaseConfig object) to my custom auth domain.

Is there anything else I need to do for this to work? How this can work out of the box without me having to write some custom redirect logic? If my react app is being served via static hosting like an S3 bucket, then I won't even have a server running. How is https://auth.myappname.com/__/auth/handler handling anything?

Much of the documentation online is talking about using firebase hosting or other firebase black magic which I **do not** want to use.

Any explanations appreciated..